# How to set height , width to image using jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to set height and width of an image using jquery?
The following is my code

```
var img = new Image();  
 // Create image
$(img).load(function(){                 
    imgdiv.append(this);
}).error(function () {  
    $('#adsloder').remove();
}).attr({ 
    id: val.ADV_ID,  
    src: val.ADV_SRC,
    title: val.ADV_TITLE,
    alt: val.ADV_ALT
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can call the [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and ,[.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) setters:

```
var img = new Image();  
 // Create image
$(img).load(function(){                 
    imgdiv.append(this);
}).error(function () {  
    $('#adsloder').remove();
}).attr({ 
    id: val.ADV_ID,  
    src: val.ADV_SRC,
    title: val.ADV_TITLE,
    alt: val.ADV_ALT
}).height(100).width(100);
```

Comment: `$('<img/>', { id: val.ADV_ID, src: val.ADV_SRC, title: val.ADV_TITLE, alt: val.ADV_ALT }).load(function() { imgdiv.append(this); }).height(100).width(100);`

Comment: @Dementic - in this case for some browsers it's important that the load handler is specified before the source, so that instant from-cache loads are handled in all cases...so while shorter, it's also not correct in all cases.  Granted, with Opera moving to webkit it's less of an issue these days.

Comment: @NickCraver Did not know that, was pretty sure jquery is doing the job for me.

Answer (score 10):

```
$(".img1").css('height','10');
$(".img1").css('width','10');
```

OR

```
$(".img1").attr('height','10');
$(".img1").attr('width','10');
```

Comment: or `$('.img1').css({ 'height': '10px', 'width': '10px' });`

Answer (score 1):

In case the image is inside `<div class="myGallery">`

```
$('div.myGallery > img').css({ 'height': '10px', 'width': '10px' });
```