# how to define the size of image like width and height which is loaded from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

i have successfully loaded images from server and shown it to the div element .but i want to resize the image as its being to large.how can i do this.here is my code for loading images from server.

```
var img = $("<img />").attr('src', url)
    .load(function() {
        if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
            alert('broken image!');
        } else {
            $("#image").append(img);
        }
    });
```

Comment: duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183863/how-to-set-height-width-to-image-using-jquery) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550880/change-image-size-wih-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `width()` and `height()` getters and setters.

```
var xDimension=150;
$(img).load(function(){ 
     // put your logic here
  }).width(xDimension).height(xDimension);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a style in your css file like this:

```
#image img{width: your width; height: your height;}
```

It will work for dynamically loaded images also.